# How to keep brightcove player in the app and not jumping to safari

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, cross-domain, brightcove

I have a PhoneGap application I am developing for iPad that uses video extensively, all of which is hosted at Brightcove. The Brightcove player code works fine when testing as a WebApp, but once compiled with PhoneGap in Xcode, the page containing the player immediately jumps out of the app and opens Safari to display the player.

I have added the appropriate domains to the ExternalHosts array, such that I am not getting any build errors mentioning whitelist problems.

Any ideas how to keep that from happening? I just want the player to load up into the app view it is located in. thx

Here's the standard Brightcove player code embedded in the page:

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>
<object id="myExperienceXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" class="BrightcoveExperience">
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
  <param name="width" value="480" />
  <param name="height" value="450" />
  <param name="playerID" value="1149493366001" />
  <param name="playerKey" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
  <param name="isVid" value="true" />
  <param name="isUI" value="true" />
  <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />

  <param name="@videoPlayer" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX" />
</object>
```

Comment: You should answer your own question with this information, and acept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was a confirmed bug and has been resolved in PhoneGap 1.2.0

Comment: I'm in cordova (phonegap) 2.0 and am having this exact issue. Was there a regression, or do i just have my own issue? Hmmm...

Comment: My bad, got it - maybe it will help someone else. Set `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView` in Cordova.plist to `YES`. Just beware of side effects this could have on other link handling (and those videos suck up events like no other, i'm getting off topic now tho...).